# How to get number data with dots within a string?

Tags: php

There is a string variable containing number data with dots , say `$x = "OP/1.1.2/DIR";` . The position of the number data may change at any circumstance by user desire by modifying it inside the application , and the slash bar may be changed by any other character ; but the dotted number data is mandatory. So how to extract the dotted number data , here `1.1.2`, from the string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
```

Breakdown:

- `\d+` look for one or more digits
- `\.` a literal decimal `.` character
- `\d+` followed by one or more digits again
- `(...)*` this means match 0 or more occurrences of this pattern
- `(?:...)` this tells the engine not to create a backreference for this group (basically, we don't use the reference, so it's pointless to have one)

You haven't given much information about the data, so I've made the following assumptions:

- The data will always contain at least one number
- The data may contain only a number without a dot
- The data may contain multi-digit numbers
- The numbers themselves may contain any number of dot/digit pairs

If any of these assumptions are incorrect, you'll have to modify the regular expression.

Example usage:

```
$x = "OP/1.1.2/DIR";

if (!preg_match('/(\d+(\.\d+)*)/', $x, $matches)) {
    // Could not find a matching number in the data - handle this appropriately
} else {
    var_dump($matches[1]); // string(5) "1.1.2"
}
```

Comment: `'/(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)/'` consumes less memory.

Comment: @Florent: Thank you for catching that.  I'll add a bit about it in the breakdown.

Comment: Is it always at $matches[1] to get the data ? or can I get it at $matches[0] ?

Comment: @pheromix: `$matches[0]` will always be the entire matching pattern.  Because in this case the entire pattern should always be the entire number (because we aren't matching surrounding context), you could use the `0` offset.  I'm in the habit of always using the `1` offset, because most expressions I write include context.  In this example, if the `/` characters in the data weren't variable, we would have stuck those in the expression as well, but then `0` would have returned them as well as the number.  I would still use `1`, though, in case you ever modify the pattern.