# How many dots are in a string. (Java)

Tags: java, regex

So, I am working on a program in which I need to check if a string has more than one dot. I went and looked at the documentation for `regex` and found this:

```
X{n,m}?  X, at least n but not more than m times
```

Following that logic I tried this:

```
mString = "He9.lo,"

if (myString.matches(".{1,2}?")){

    System.out.print("it works");
}
```

But that does not works (It does not gives any error, it just wont do what is inside the `if`). I think the problem is that is thinking that the dot means something else. I also looked at this question: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452678/how-to-get-number-data-with-dots-within-a-string) but is for php and I don't know how to apply that to java.

**EDIT**: Basically I want to know if a string contains more than one dot, for example:

He......lo (True, contains more than one), hel.llo (False, contains one), ..hell.o (True Contains more than one).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you accept non regex answers: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurences-of-substring-in-a-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, your regex contains a bug. You could either fix that (escape the dot), or use `String.contains` instead:

```
if (myString.contains("..")){
    System.out.print("it works");
}
```

This will match for two consecutive dots. If you're also looking for two dots anywhere in the string (like in the string "He.llo.") you could do

```
if(myString.indexOf('.', myString.indexOf('.') + 1) != -1) {
    System.out.print("it works"); //there are two or more dots in this string
}
```

Comment: Yes but that would not work if the dot is in the middle. Like He.lo

Comment: But He.lo doesn't have two dots... I have updated my answer though.

Comment: I tried `tempString.indexOf('.', tempString.indexOf('.') + 1)` but it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean"

Comment: Sorry about that bug - it's fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

A dot in a regular expression means "any character". So if you want *actual dots* you need to escape it with a backslash - and then you need to escape the backslash within Java itself...

```
if (myString.matches("\\.{1,2}?")){
```

Next you need to understand that `matches` tries to match the *whole* text - it's not just trying to find the pattern *within* the string.

It's not entirely clear what your requirements are - is it just "more than one dot together" or "more than one dot anywhere in the text"? If it's the latter, this should do it:

```
if (myString.matches(".*\\..*\\..*")) {
```

... in other words, anything, then a dot, then anything, then a dot, then anything - where the "anything" can be "nothing". So this will match "He..llo" and "H.e.llo", but not "He.llo".

Hopefully that's what you want. If you *literally* just want "it must have .. in it somewhere" then it's easier:

```
if (myString.contains(".."))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried that and it does not do what's inside the if statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but according to the documentation it should look if the dot appears 1, but no more than 2 times in the whole string. Is that correct?

Comment: Basically what I want to see if there is more than one dot in the whole string.

Answer (score 6):

[StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) makes it more immediately obvious what is happening.

```
boolean multipleDots = StringUtils.countMatches( myString, "." ) > 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answers are better, however, just for a different perspective

```
if (myString.indexOf(".") != myString.lastIndexOf(".")) {
    // More then one dot...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` or `\` to escape special characters, which the dot character `.` is, meaning any character.

For example using brackets to escape it:
`myString.matches("[.]{1,2}?")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use escape sequence characters for those characters which are already part of the regex metacharacters set

> `\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? . < >`

Since the "." character is also part of the meta characters set, You need to use "\." to match the string pattern with multiple "." characters.

in this case `myString.matches("\\.{1,2}?")`

Answer (score 1):

this solution works perfectly for me if I want to check does the string has 2 dots. In other words it's a validation for URL

```
private boolean isValid(String urlString) {
        try {
            String extensionValidator;
            extensionValidator = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            if (urlString.indexOf('.', urlString.indexOf('.') + 1) != -1) {
                if (extensionValidator.length() >= 2 && urlString.contains(".")) {
                    return URLUtil.isValidUrl(urlString) && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlString).matches();
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }

        return false;
    }
```